# My Ubuntu + i3 freezes randomly without any log

Tags: ubuntu, x11, swap, i3, compton

I'm using Ubuntu server 21.10 with i3 along with Compton.

Everything thing works fine, but sometimes (every 2 or 3 days) it freezes completely and no more action could be taken, nothing works and I couldn't even find any log in journanctl or other places.

I have no idea what is going on.

My computer is on constantly and this happens also when swap or memory has almost 30% or 40% free space.

Memory 16 GB

Swap 20 GB

Comment: Overheating? Check your fans, airflow, and dust inside the computer.

Comment: I don't think so, I was using this computer for long time with windows on it without such a problem